# How do I convert a keras.datasets.cifar100 from (32,32,3) to (128,128,3)?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras

How can I convert a cifar100 image data set to (128,128,3) and pass it to the model?

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)=tensworflow.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()
I want to convert x_train, x_test above.

x_train.reshape(50000,128,128,3) doesn't work．

Answer (score 0):

```
func = lambda x : tf.image.resize(x , (128 , 128))

x_train = tf.py_function(func, [x_train], tf.float32)

print(x_train.shape)
```

Output:

```
(50000, 128, 128, 3)
```

Above method is slow and inefficient way to do this, but instead for **best performance** try this

```
func = lambda x , y : (tf.image.resize(x , (128 , 128)), y)

train_examples = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train))

train_examples = train_examples.map(func, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

train_examples.take(1)
```

Output:

```
<TakeDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None))>
```